# YouTube counters history

Tags: youtube

In YouTube videos, there are comments and two popular ones stay on the top. I see that for some hot videos on political views ([like this one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2m4SCUaBHS8), which is very hot these days), popular comments disappear and less popular appear (though, they support the same idea). I have also seen the same [here](http://michail-shor.livejournal.com/81506.html), where video likes were not accounted and even slowly and systematically decremented. How is it possible and can this be traced somehow?

I guess that there may be a limited history of comments and the top comments disappear as they are removed fall out of the history.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an issue that no longer exists.

Answer (score -1):

What your referring to is similar to the views that freeze at 301. Which is actually quite interesting, as I have seen views rapidly rise, and then **HALT!**, it suddenly stops at 301.

Numberphile has a very informative video on this theory:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oIkhgagvrjI

Comment: No, it cannot be a correct answer because I am talking about popular videos that have over 100 000 views. They cannot stop at 301 therefore. Secondly, I am talking about popular comments disappeared and upvotes (+likes) slowly going down. What does this has to do with the viewcounter stopped at 301?

Comment: @Val Sorry about that. I was relating to the ideology of the 100,000 views, which seemed interesting in correlation to your question.